# Make multiple objects within a movieclip disappear at once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have multiple buttons within a movieclip "mc_circlebtn". I want to make all of them disappear at once with actionscript 3. How can I do it? Would really appreciate it if I could get some fast responses. Thank you.

Comment: If they have specific name or something just loop through all children, check name and if it's `XXX` then set visible to false.

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail a bit maybe with an example. i am quite new to actionscript 3.

Comment: Sure, just update your question with some code for context.

Comment: **mc_circlebtn.removeChildren();** http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChildren() Keep in mind that this will only remove them from display list, not destroy them, nor unsubscribe listeners from their events if any.

Comment: Edit your question and show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying, but maybe this is what you need, run this code when you want to remove buttons:

```
for (var i:int = mc_circlebtn.numChildren-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
      mc_circlebtn.removeChildAt(i);
}
```